# "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions" in my chat app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a React Chat app and during accessing my firebase I got this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

The error occurs in the assignment to this.removeListener.

The following are the lines of code in which I got the error :

```
this.removeListener = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('Messages')
    .doc(this.groupChatId)
    .collection(this.groupChatId)
    .onSnapshot(Snapshot => {
      Snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change=>{
        if(change.type === LoginString.DOC) {
          this.listMessage.push(change.doc.data());
        }
    })
})
```

Please help!

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about what line this error occurs on.  I also suggest constructing a complete, minimal code sample that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  What you have now seems incomplete.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Doug Stevenson, I have edited my question please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by enclosing the entire expression to the right of the "=" in parentheses i.e from before "firebase" to the last line after "})". I think that actually helped in evaluating the expression first and then make the assignment.

Please let me know if it works for any of you also. Thank You!